# Play! framework 2.7 - Cannot connect to database

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, playframework, database-connection

i am trying to connect to my postgres database from my play 2.7 application.
The database is an docker image that is initialized with

```
docker run -d --name backend_local - p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=markos -e POSTGRES-PASSWORD=**** -e POSTGRES_DB=backend_db --restart always registry.gitlab....
```

My configuration file looks like this

```
# Database
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/backend_db"
db.default.username="markos"
db.default.password="****"
db.default.logSql=true
```

cant see something wrong with the connection but still i am getting **Cannot initialize to database[default]**

the logs i am getting

```
2020-05-23 15:44:13.044+0200 [error] application - 

! @7fpl591k9 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot initialize to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:168)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:1014)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$initialize$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.initialize(DefaultDBApi.scala:68)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:93)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:77)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:77)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:168)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:1014)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:68)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:248)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:140)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$initialize$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.initialize(DefaultDBApi.scala:68)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:93)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:958)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConfig.toHikariConfig(HikariCPModule.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.$anonfun$create$1(HikariCPModule.scala:55)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:52)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:248)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:140)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.$anonfun$initialize$1(DefaultDBApi.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
```

Comment: Unsure why are you using ip address with -p option, it should be just port.

Comment: To bind the port with localhost and not any other address

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: The error message is basically meaning that the `url` setting is missing. Your config is probably not applied at all. Try to print out your config e.g. in your controller and ensure that you really have the correct settings.

Comment: @cbley i cant really print it because the app dont even starts. Is there another way to check this ? Is there a chance that i am missing some dependencies?

Comment: @ma You can also add a default Module which is given the config before Guice is trying to instantiate classes. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaPlayModules#Creating-and-migrating-Play-modules Alternatively, just use a debugger and look at the config.

Comment: @ma BTW, which Play version do you use specifically? 2.7.5? Maybe you can create a minimal reprroducable example? Or show your complete application.conf (with real values redacted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my local_dev.conf that was handling the database configurations was misplaced outside from the conf file where it should be located originally!